# MongoDB Mac /data/db read-only

Tags: mongodb

Following along with a Udemy course and I need to start up a MongoDB server. During installation unable to mkdir -p data/db. I assume this is the reason I am unable to run mongod server properly or use mongo shell. Any help is appreciated.

Attempted sudo mkdir, multiple re-installations in case of error on my end. Found a few other solutions that did not work for me. Just need to be able to mkdir -p /data/db without getting read-only file error.